# Output to be saved in file named same as the input file

Tags: shell, grep

I have one input file and run some command but want the output to be saved with the same name as the input file has.

I tried below command but it makes the output file blank:

```
cat file1 | grep "YISHA" > file1
```

Comment: Simplest way is use temp-file `grep "YISHA" file1 > file1.tmp ; mv file1{tmp,}`

Comment: The answers cover the solutions nicely. Just to comment on why this happens: the order of execution in a pipeline is not sequential, bash has to set up "plumbing" before it runs `cat` and `grep`: it needs to connect the output of `cat` to the input of `grep` and the output of `grep` to the output file before the pipeline is run, so `file1` is already empty and ready for writing into, when `cat` opens it.

Comment: Related: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408) — [Warning regarding ‘>’](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/23408).

Answer (score 8):

On GNU system, you could use `sed` (the GNU implementation):

```
sed -i -n '/YISHA/p' file1
```

The FreeBSD or OS/X equivalent:

```
sed -i '' -n '/YISHA/p' file1
```

or using `sponge` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
grep "YISHA" file1 | sponge file1
```

Comment: for sponge it is showing command not found at terminal

Comment: @yisha: you need to install `moreutils`.

Answer (score 4):

Your shell will likely get you a secure temp file on request:

```
grep "YISHA" <<IN > file
$(cat file)
IN
```

That will drop blank lines from tail of `file` though *(which shouldn't be relevant unless you're `grep`ping for blank lines)*. If that should matter, then just `echo .` after `cat` in the command substitution and drop the last line.

Another option available to you is `dd`. For example:

```
seq 5000000 >/tmp/temp
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 38888896 Mar 11 04:20 /tmp/temp
```

Just a dummy file large enough to outweigh any pipe buffer.

```
</tmp/temp grep 5\$ |
dd bs=4k of=/tmp/temp conv=notrunc,sync
```

You can see that I exceeded the size of any possible pipe buffer:

```
949+1 records in
950+0 records out
3891200 bytes (3.9 MB) copied, 0.164471 s, 23.7 MB/s
```

When the `notrunc` conversion is specified, `dd` doesn't touch the output file except to write over what it reads in. With `seek=` you could even put that  input data at some other offset in the file if you liked. But... the file still needs truncating. You can see that `dd` flushed its last input buffer as well: 949+1 records were read in, but 950 were written out - `dd` synced it's last input block to the full 4k size w/ nulls *(which is a generally reasonable block size to choose when accepting piped input from tools that use stdio - such as `grep`)*.

So...

```
ls -l /tmp/temp; tail /tmp/temp
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 38888896 Mar 11 04:22 /tmp/temp

4999991
4999992
4999993
4999994
4999995
4999996
4999997
4999998
4999999
5000000
```

It's still the same file for everything beyond what `dd` wrote.

But...

```
dd if=/dev/null bs=4k seek=950 of=/tmp/temp
```

...we can truncate it to the point that `dd` wrote to it, and...

```
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000153783 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

...it looks like nothing happened, except that...

```
ls -l /tmp/temp; tail /tmp/temp
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 3891200 Mar 11 04:25 /tmp/temp
4999915
4999925
4999935
4999945
4999955
4999965
4999975
4999985
4999995
```

`dd` cuts it short that time. In truth, though, there is that last `sync`ed partial block at the tail of the file, so...

```
tail /tmp/temp | wc -c 

2383
```

...there are a bunch of nulls at the end.

Comment: Except with `zsh`, that won't work with binary files (files containing NUL bytes). Like `sponge`, that stores the whole file in memory (and in a temp files with most shells).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - won't work w/ binary files as written in most any shell - that's true. Some tricks can be done with `/dev/fd/num` links though. I sometimes do `cmd 3<<! 3<<!\n!\n$(cmd >/dev/fd/3)\n!\n` but different shells handle that differently. Thanks for the edit. I'm really sleepy, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

When removing data, you can write the file over itself and truncate it afterwards:

```
{
  grep YISHA
  perl -e 'truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT'
} < file 1<> file
```

Of course here, you can do everything in `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if /YISHA/; END{truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT}' < file 1<> file
```

`perl` also has a `-i` option for in-place editing (the one that GNU `sed` copied):

```
perl -ni -e 'print if /YISHA/' file
```

But note that like `sed`, it creates a new file with the same name, it doesn't really rewrite the file *in-place*, which means inode numbers and other attributes of the file could be affected in the process. It will also break symlinks.

Comment: It will break _hard_ links to this file, and will break if the file itself is a symlink pointing elsewhere. If it's a regular file and there are symlinks pointing _to_ it, no problem.