# Loop through files and join horizontally

Tags: paste

I am trying to do the following:

1. Loop through a list of files
2. Edit each file and output a "trimmed" file
3. Horizontally join each trimmed file in turn to a pre-made master file

I have steps 1 & 2 working, but can't get 3 to work.

**Example**

MASTER FILE:

```
Col1   Col2
A       1
B       1
C       2
```

TRIMMED FILE for file S1:

```
S1.Col3    S1.Col4
0            1
1            1
1            1
```

OUTPUT I WANT after S1 & S2 have been joined to MASTER:

```
Col1   Col2   S1.Col3   S1.Col4   S2.Col3   S2.Col4
A       1       0         1          0        1
B       1       1         1          1        0
C       2       1         1          0        0
```

After each loop, I've tried running something like:

```
paste MASTER.txt S1.txt > MASTER.txt
```

However, instead of the above, I get a file with only the last S file's data.  I tried running this without outputting and outside of the loop, everything works fine.  Thanks in advance for any answers.

For completion, here is a very simplified breakdown of my for loop.

```
for FILE in FILELIST
do
    cut -f4,6 $FILE > ${FILE}_trimmed.txt
    paste MASTER.txt ${FILE}_trimmed.txt > MASTER.txt
done
```

Comment: hint: the `> MASTER.txt` clobbers the file before `paste` can get to its contents.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I think.  I initially tried `paste MASTER.txt ${FILE}_trimmed.txt > MASTER2.txt` but that obviously doesn't work if I'm looping through files.  I just end up with the final S file joined to the MASTER.  So, still unsure how to get the result I'm looking for.  I'm used to working in R, where I could possibly store as a temp variable and then output the file at the end.  Unsure if that is plausible here or a good way of doing this...

Comment: simplistically, change `paste MASTER.txt ${FILE}_trimmed.txt > MASTER.txt` to `paste MASTER.txt ${FILE}_trimmed.txt > MASTER2.txt && mv MASTER2.txt MASTER.txt`

Comment: I see.   That's perfect.    I've created an answer, but will delete if you would prefer to explain it more thoroughly.

Comment: No problems, +1 as well

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189473/38906

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to 1_CR , who answered this in the comments.

The `> MASTER.txt` is truncating the file before the paste actually completes the horizontal join.  The answer is to output to a temporary file (e.g. MASTER2.txt) and then rename it (with the mv command) to the proper file name.

My Old Code:

```
paste MASTER.txt ${FILE}_trimmed.txt > MASTER.txt
```

Fixed Code:

```
paste MASTER.txt ${FILE}_trimmed.txt > MASTER2.txt && mv MASTER2.txt MASTER.txt
```